# Unexpected ERROR 1556 (HY000) at line 45: You can't use locks with log tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to restore dump made by mariadbdump 11.2 by the same version of mariadb client, it drops at the attempt to lock the InnoDB table.

```sql
--------------
LOCK TABLES `Component1` WRITE
--------------

ERROR 1556 (HY000) at line 45: You can't use locks with log tables
```

The table is actually InnoDB, no kidding.

```sql
[db]> SHOW CREATE TABLE Component1;
CREATE TABLE `Component1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
…
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53652 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci


$ mysql --version
mysql from 11.2.3-MariaDB, client 15.2 for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

What's going on?

Comment: The table you're trying to /create/ might be InnoDB, but it's complaining about trying to lock the table that's /already there/.  That might not be InnoDB.  
Is there a reason you're "restoring" over an existing database?

Comment: The create statement was provided to prove that the table is INNODB. Of course it is in the database already, I do not have a habit of dropping and creating tables daily.

Comment: You may find this link useful.

Comment: Search for 'mariadb error 1556' and you may see that logs typically use CSV storage engine.  Soooo - this may be a multi factor problem from design process.

Comment: All links point to the bug reports resolved years ago. Again, I do not use any log tables in my schema. They all InnoDB tables. Kindly read the question, please.